Puppeteer Recaptcha plugin not finding turnstile challenges
I have cloudflare protected website and came across puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha that integrates 2captcha to solve the captcha challenges.
After a lot of debugging I found that the plugin is not even detecting any captcha on the page.
The browser page is still on this screen

Code Snippet
import pptr from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import { PuppeteerExtraPluginAdblocker } from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker';
import { PuppeteerExtraPluginRecaptcha } from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha';

pptr
  .use(StealthPlugin())
  .use(new PuppeteerExtraPluginAdblocker({ blockTrackers: true, blockTrackersAndAnnoyances: true }))
  .use(
    new PuppeteerExtraPluginRecaptcha({
      throwOnError: true,
      visualFeedback: true,
      provider: { id: '2captcha', token: '<REDACTED>' },
    }),
  )
  .launch({ headless: false })
  .then((browser) => browser.newPage())
  .then(async (page) => {
    await page.goto('https://tbhaxor.com');
    const captcha = await page.findRecaptchas();
    console.log(captcha);
    const { solutions } = await page.solveRecaptchas();
    await page.enterRecaptchaSolutions(solutions);
  });

